# Is it possible to add show all pages in the rows per page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I have these rows per page options `10,15,100` is it possible to add an option to view all the rows? And if so, how? I can't seem to find it in the documentation:

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/muidatatables-custom-toolbar-forked-xfhb5h?file=/index.js:1372-1394

```
  const options = {
    search: searchBtn,
    download: downloadBtn,
    print: printBtn,
    viewColumns: viewColumnBtn,
    filter: filterBtn,
    filterType: "dropdown",
    responsive: "standard",
    tableBodyHeight,
    tableBodyMaxHeight,
    onTableChange: (action, state) => {
      console.log(action);
      console.dir(state);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achive that, remove `tableBodyHeight,tableBodyMaxHeight,` from options and add following props to your `options` object:

```
    responsive: "scrollFullHeight",
    pagination: false,
    rowsPerPageOptions: [],
```

So, your options object should look like this :

```
const options = {
    search: searchBtn,
    download: downloadBtn,
    print: printBtn,
    viewColumns: viewColumnBtn,
    filter: filterBtn,
    filterType: "dropdown",
    responsive: "scrollFullHeight",
    pagination: false,
    rowsPerPageOptions: [],

    onTableChange: (action, state) => {
      console.log(action);
      console.dir(state);
    }
  };
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/muidatatables-custom-toolbar-forked-ty1lw7?file=/index.js:1372-1454) is a working example.

Comment: But I won't be able to use the pagination anymore?

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to see all rows, so why do you need pagination than?